# Create a Dynamic & Fixed Width Column Structure using Bootstrap 4 Grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am looking to use Bootstrap 4 and create a simple grid where I can put content. I want to have all columns fixed except 1 which is the one on the left and will have a name. The columns on the right are 7 x input fields and 1 div which I would like to keep right of the page and a fixed width.

On resize only the column on the left resizes.

I am trying to achieve it using flex in bootstrap but failing to get it to work locally.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: wrap all in the elements into a wrapper and apply a simply css-grid: `display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto repeat(7, 60px) 100px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a css-grid by wrapping all the elements and applying `display: grid;` to it.

Then use `grid-template-columns: auto repeat(7, 60px) 100px;` to achieve the wanted behavior. `repeat(7, 60px)` will give the next 7 elements an exact width of `60px` followed by the last element with `100px`. The value `auto` at the beginning will automatically give all remaining space to the first element.

```css
body {
  min-width: 600px;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto repeat(7, 60px) 100px;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div></div>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool man, thanks! So basically you are saying I don't even need to rely on BS4 for this! thanks

Comment: is this type of css you are using have good compatibility with browsers or is it something only modern browsers can understand?

Comment: css-grid is supported by every single browser with exeption of IE.

Comment: Seems 10/11 have partial support, any suggestion if I need to support IE? https://caniuse.com/css-grid